# What is the natural position that a person normally falls in a violent encounter?

Tags: falling, positions, attack

In any case that I or anyone else should be engaged in a violent encounter by any man in general, should he fall, what position would he most likely fall and what position would he naturally be when he lands and what positions would he be after he lands?

I ask because some martial arts teach moves against a person that is lying flat with his back to the ground. Should it become necessary to inflict harm on the attacker once he is on the ground, it would be important to prepare ahead and practice against an attacker in positions he would most likely be in.

In rare situations most people would never want to be in, when attacked by such a violent attacker, it would be necessary to injure the attacker in order to walk away from the encounter.

I ask specifically about a man being the attacker. I most likely would be attacked by a man.

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but self defence situations are by their nature chaotic and unpredictable.  I think you would be best served in finding a group or club to train something with. I personally disagree with Steve about prioritising 'competitive sports' over 'self defence' systems (I don't think it matters which you choose so long as you are not learning from a charlatan).  But you need to learn some technique and to do that you need to physically practice with training partners under the supervision of an instructor.  There really isn't another way.

Comment: The reason why I say you should look at competitive grappling, as opposed to doing canned kata based training, is that you have an element of unpredictability. People will fall exactly the way they're told to fall unless you have this competitive unpredictability. Then you'll see for real what can happen.

Comment: There is a middle ground Steve. I agree kata training on it's own is lacking but you can spar and even roll without a competitive element. Either way you need to learn a few pair form techniques first though.

Comment: If the attacker is on the ground then you have a head start on getting away, in a self-defense situation. Why attack someone already on the ground? How do they still pose a threat?

Comment: @MichaelFoster It depends on the situation, but it might be that they are able to get up from the ground quickly enough to still pose a threat if you try to get away.  Also if there are two attackers you may not be able to get away from the second attacker.  Self defence situations are relatively rare in a lot of countries, but among possible outcomes this isn't all that unlikely.

Comment: @MichaelFoster I think it's mostly about what you can expect. Skill at fighting is at least half about being familiar with every situation you can find yourself in: Standing toe-to-toe punching and kicking, clinching, throws / takedowns, ground, weapons, multiple attackers, etc. You won't just freeze and not know what to do then. So if you know how someone might fall, you can recognize it and then know what to do. Sometimes that means running away. Sometimes it means following up with something. Someone who falls can get up quickly or can be close enough to take you down from the ground.

Answer (score 3):

The question asks in what position do people most often land in after falling down during a fight.

Given a lack of statistics about real world fights in general, I don't think we'll have a definitive answer here. So a lot of what you'll get are going to be opinions.

Based on my observation only (not statistical), I've witnessed people falling to the ground in 3 common variations. First variation is when someone gets punched in the face (usually a sucker punch), then they tend to fall and end up on their backs if they're knocked out. If they're still conscious, they quickly get onto their knees and hands to try to get back up.

The second variation is when they slip and fall, they usually land on one of their hands and push themselves back up quickly. They might land on their butts and one hand to brace themselves. I've seen this happen over and over again in real fights. It's rare they're going to use both hands to prevent their fall, because they're usually going down on one side. They might begin to fall backwards, too, but twist themselves and use one arm to break the fall and push themselves back up. They can also break their arms this way, by stiff-arming the landing.

And the third variation is when they're tripped or thrown, they land on their butt, back, or head. If they land on their butt, then they often continue rolling backwards onto their back before rocking themselves immediately back up to a standing or crouching position. And instinctively, people often grab onto the person throwing them or taking them down in order to prevent themselves from falling too badly.

There are a lot of other possibilities beyond those. Some may land belly down, especially after being taken down from a standing arm-bar, for example. Some may land in a seated position. Some land at your feet and can now snake their legs around yours to trip you. Some just sort of bounce right back up instantly instead of staying down. Some roll away. Etc.

If you're dealing with a trained grappler, there are a lot more possibilities than that, too. They might cartwheel out of it (damn ninjas!). They might grab on to you to reorient themselves as they're falling, and then use that momentum to pull you down, instead. They can land in a squat position. They can do a hand spring or even a somersault and land on their feet. Believe it or not, all of these spectacular landings have been seen in competitive grappling of all kinds.

So my advice if you're trying to study this situation is that you probably want to train in a martial art that does a lot of throws and take-downs against a non-compliant partner. That would be stuff like Brazilian Jiu Jitsu, wrestling, Judo, Shuai-jiao, Pankration, and Sambo. These styles are competitive, and so your opponent can often fall in unpredictable ways. By training this way frequently and for many years, you can gain skill in almost all conceivable positions in which someone lands.

Hope that helps.